# Dagger 2 Mocking Content Resolver class

Tags: kotlin, android-contentresolver

I have a `ContentResolver` that is injected to my `fragment` using `Dagger2`. I want to mock this in espresso so in my test do I do:

1: mock it in the class as an external variable

```
@Mock val mockContentResolver = MockContentResolver()
```

or

2: mock it inside the method

```
@Test
fun testContentResolver() {
    val contentResolver = mock(ContentResolver::class.java)
}
```

Or am I doing it completely wrong and there is another method to correctly mock the `ContentResolver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "double mock" your val here:

```
@Mock val mockContentResolver = MockContentResolver()
```

Either go for

```
@Mock lateinit var mockContentResolver: ContentResolver
```

in which case Mockito mocks your field. This is also equivalent to your second approach. The other possibility is:

```
val mockContentResolver = MockContentResolver()
```

with assigns the mocking implementation of the android test package. This is totally different to the Mockito version. Mockito mocks your object whereas `MockContentResolver` is an (more or less empty) implementation of the `ContentResolver` class.

I think it depends what you want to achieve. If you want to test which methods of your ContentResolver got called you better go with the Mockito version. If you want to mimic a certain behavior of your ContentResolver you can go for the `MockContentResolver` variant. Keep in mind that you have to implement all used methods there. Otherwise it will throw many `UnsupportedOperationExceptions`.